# OpenGL: Deform (scale) stencil shadow from light source

Tags: opengl, transform, shadow

I have a basic stencil shadow functioning in my game engine. I'm trying to deform the shadow based on the lighting direction, which I have:

```
/*
 * @brief Applies translation, rotation and scale for the shadow of the specified
 * entity. In order to reuse the vertex arrays from the primary rendering
 * pass, the shadow origin must transformed into model-view space.
 */
static void R_RotateForMeshShadow_default(const r_entity_t *e) {
    vec3_t origin, delta;

    if (!e) {
        glPopMatrix();
        return;
    }

    R_TransformForEntity(e, e->lighting->shadow_origin, origin);

    VectorSubtract(e->lighting->shadow_origin, e->origin, delta);
    const vec_t scale = 1.0 + VectorLength(delta) / LIGHTING_MAX_SHADOW_DISTANCE;

    /*const vec_t dot = DotProduct(e->lighting->shadow_normal, e->lighting->dir);

    const vec_t sy = sin(Radians(e->angles[YAW]));
    const vec_t cy = cos(Radians(e->angles[YAW]));*/

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(origin[0], origin[1], origin[2] + 1.0);

    glRotatef(-e->angles[PITCH], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glScalef(scale, scale, 0.0);
```

}

I've commented out the dot product of the ground plane (shadow_normal) and lighting direction, as well as the sin and cos of the yaw of the model, because while I'm pretty sure they are what I need to augment the scale of the shadow, I don't know what the correct formula is to yield a perspective-correct deformation. For someone who better understands projections, this is probably child's play.. for me, I'm stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to achieve the desired effect by managing my own matrices and adapting code from the SGI's OpenGL Cookbook. The code uses LordHavoc's matrix library from his DarkPlaces Quake engine. Inline comments call out the major steps. Here's the full code:

```
/*
 * @brief Projects the model view matrix for the given entity onto the shadow
 * plane. A perspective shear is then applied using the standard planar shadow
 * deformation from SGI's cookbook, adjusted for Quake's negative planes:
 *
 * ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node192.html
 */
static void R_RotateForMeshShadow_default(const r_entity_t *e, r_shadow_t *s) {
    vec4_t pos, normal;
    matrix4x4_t proj, shear;
    vec_t dot;

    if (!e) {
        glPopMatrix();
        return;
    }

    const cm_bsp_plane_t *p = &s->plane;

    // project the entity onto the shadow plane
    vec3_t vx, vy, vz, t;
    Matrix4x4_ToVectors(&e->matrix, vx, vy, vz, t);

    dot = DotProduct(vx, p->normal);
    VectorMA(vx, -dot, p->normal, vx);

    dot = DotProduct(vy, p->normal);
    VectorMA(vy, -dot, p->normal, vy);

    dot = DotProduct(vz, p->normal);
    VectorMA(vz, -dot, p->normal, vz);

    dot = DotProduct(t, p->normal) - p->dist;
    VectorMA(t, -dot, p->normal, t);

    Matrix4x4_FromVectors(&proj, vx, vy, vz, t);

    glPushMatrix();

    glMultMatrixf((GLfloat *) proj.m);

    // transform the light position and shadow plane into model space
    Matrix4x4_Transform(&e->inverse_matrix, s->illumination->light.origin, pos);
    pos[3] = 1.0;

    const vec_t *n = p->normal;
    Matrix4x4_TransformPositivePlane(&e->inverse_matrix, n[0], n[1], n[2], p->dist, normal);

    // calculate shearing, accounting for Quake's negative plane equation
    normal[3] = -normal[3];
    dot = DotProduct(pos, normal) + pos[3] * normal[3];

    shear.m[0][0] = dot - pos[0] * normal[0];
    shear.m[1][0] = 0.0 - pos[0] * normal[1];
    shear.m[2][0] = 0.0 - pos[0] * normal[2];
    shear.m[3][0] = 0.0 - pos[0] * normal[3];
    shear.m[0][1] = 0.0 - pos[1] * normal[0];
    shear.m[1][1] = dot - pos[1] * normal[1];
    shear.m[2][1] = 0.0 - pos[1] * normal[2];
    shear.m[3][1] = 0.0 - pos[1] * normal[3];
    shear.m[0][2] = 0.0 - pos[2] * normal[0];
    shear.m[1][2] = 0.0 - pos[2] * normal[1];
    shear.m[2][2] = dot - pos[2] * normal[2];
    shear.m[3][2] = 0.0 - pos[2] * normal[3];
    shear.m[0][3] = 0.0 - pos[3] * normal[0];
    shear.m[1][3] = 0.0 - pos[3] * normal[1];
    shear.m[2][3] = 0.0 - pos[3] * normal[2];
    shear.m[3][3] = dot - pos[3] * normal[3];

    glMultMatrixf((GLfloat *) shear.m);

    Matrix4x4_Copy(&s->matrix, &proj);
}
```

The full implementation of this lives here:
https://github.com/jdolan/quake2world/blob/master/src/client/renderer/r_mesh_shadow.c